# Converting an Image to Byte Array in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps

In WindowsStoreApps i want to convert an Local Image from solution explorer to byte array and then to base64 string.please guide me.The code I have tried so far is as below.

```
public async Task<string> ToBase64()
{
  Byte[] ByteResult = null;

  string bs64 = null;
  if (url != null)
  {
      HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
      ByteResult = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);     
  }
  bs64 = Convert.ToBase64String(ByteResult);

  return bs64;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you want to convert an image named MyImage.png from Assets folder then below code will return the base64 string of that image.

```
private async Task DoWork()
{
    var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/MyImage.png"));
    var b64 = await ConvertStorageFileToBase64String(file);
}

private async Task<string> ConvertStorageFileToBase64String(StorageFile File)
{
    var stream = await File.OpenReadAsync();

    using (var dataReader = new DataReader(stream))
    {
        var bytes = new byte[stream.Size];
        await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
        dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of code

```
StorageFile file = <Your  File>;
var bytes = new Byte[0];
using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
{
  var reader = new DataReader(fileStream.GetInputStreamAt(0));
  bytes = new Byte[fileStream.Size];
  await reader.LoadAsync((uint)fileStream.Size);
  reader.ReadBytes(bytes);
}

string imageInStringFormat = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```